# Optimizing a grid of dots with regard to distances (python)

Tags: python, optimization, grid, distance

I'm facing an issue on which I'm stuck between time of calculus and constrains...

1. **Easy case :**

I have a grid of dots somewhat equally distributed onto a 3D grid (first picture).

NB : you don't see it there but there is a 3rd axis perpendicular to the grid - there are 125 dots (5 x 5 x 5 for each side)

[3D grid with dots distributed ~ equally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mh9Hr.png)

My goal is, taking a distance given by noise statistics (we will take 0.03 for this case), to fill the grid with those conditions :

- The dot is **randomly generated** and sent through a distance condition test which will decide wether it keeps it or not
- The distance condition : if a dot is at the distance 0.03 +/- 10% from an other point, it can be placed into the grid, if not, it's removed.

Here is an example of a filled grid :

[Badly filled grid (still in 3D)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46LQR.png)

The thing is, here there are a lot of white space which i would like to remove.

For more details, here is a plot of all the distances from **one point to its closest neighbour** :

[Histogram of distances from dots their closest neighbour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3AZ5.png)

The red rectangle is where i would like all the blue bars to stack, between 0.03 - 10% and 0.03 + 10% in this case.

The major problem is that, because it's randomly generated, I have to generate a lot of dots to hope that even only one will fit in the constraint. Here it's a relatively "easy case" because afterwards, I will have to apply this on :

2. **Hard case :**

   - Dots **not equally distributed** into a base of **more than 10 axis**
   - Number of dots up to 1000 and more

I'm not a crack in python, I only know the basics (numpy, matplotlib.pyplot), and am pretty comfortable with charts, arrays, loops, however my code is not optimized in terms of time of calculus for those kind of tasks as :

- One dot is generated
- Its distance from dots is calculated for **every other dot** (i don't know what else to do to prevent scanning the whole list..)
- If one dot is closer to the previous one, it becomes "the closest one"
- If the distance from "the closest one" is in the constraint, it's not removed.

If anyone has a simple idea or some advices, it would be nice, I also hope I did explain well (I tried to keep the most important stuff only, and tried to write in proper english also :) ).

Thanks for reading,

Nathan.

EDIT : Simplified code here, as it will probably help answering more easily !
I directly added the non equally distributed grid (A, B).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.close("all")

A = np.random.rand(100)
B = np.random.rand(100)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(A, B,".")
plt.grid()

Nfillers = 10000
SNRD = 0.03

for i in range(Nfillers):
    a, b = np.random.rand(2)
    A = np.hstack((A, np.atleast_1d(a)))
    B = np.hstack((B, np.atleast_1d(b)))
    DCN = 1E+308 # Distance Closest Neighbor
    for j in range(len(A)): # len(A) is updated with each iteration
        D1 = A[j] - a
        D2 = B[j] - a
        distance = np.sqrt(D1**2 + D2**2)
        if distance != 0:
            if distance < DCN:
                DCN = distance
    if DCN < 0.9*SNRD or DCN > 1.1*SNRD:
        A = np.delete(A, len(A)-1)
        B = np.delete(B, len(B)-1)

    print i

plt.figure()
plt.plot(A, B, ".")
plt.grid()
```

EDIT 2: Quicker code :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

A = np.random.rand(100)
B = np.random.rand(100)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(A, B,".")
plt.grid()

Nfillers = 100000
SNRD = 0.03

for i in range(Nfillers):
    a, b = np.random.rand(2)
    DCN = np.min(np.sqrt((A - a)**2 + (B - b)**2))
    if DCN > 0.9*SNRD and DCN < 1.1*SNRD:
        A = np.hstack((A, np.atleast_1d(a)))
        B = np.hstack((B, np.atleast_1d(b)))

    print(i)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(A, B, ".")
plt.grid()
```

Comment: Nice problem, quite interesting. One thing missing although, the code! Anyway, how are you generating randomly the dots? I guess it's a normal distribution, so just change the mean to have more dots in the area you need. For the distance computation, if you want to really speed up the computation, don't loop on list, but compute a numpy  ndarray of distance. Can't really give more advice without the code.

Comment: what I don't fully understand is that you want the points to be random, but with a certain distance from each other. So what I would simply do is: generate a random point and then within the given distance generate the next random point etc. You do this 1000 times and voila 1000 semi-random points within the given distance to its closest neighbour.

Comment: thanks for the ideas, for the loop tip, I'll try to do it with ndarrays then (i never really got which ways are going faster in terms of computation speeds. For the "semi-random" tip, it could be appliable here but I would like to translate to the first layer of my code because : 1] 3 random numbers generated 2] They are combined to create a sample 3] Sample is projected into the base. It might work :) great idea !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't included any code but here is one rough idea of how to speed up these sorts of problems (computing distance between many points).

Partition the space into blocks roughly the size of the distance required, `d`. This could be a mapping of the block number to the list of points E.g. `blocks[i,j,k] = list_of_points`. Then when you generate a new point, you only need to check adjacent blocks. Something like:

```
new_point = random_point()
i, j, k = get_block_indices(new_point)

for ai in (i-1, i, i+1):
    for aj in (j-1, j, j+1):
        for ak in (k-1, k, k+1):
            for other_point in blocks[ai, aj, ak]:
                # check whether other_point is too close
                found_close_other_point = check(new_point, other_point, d)
                if found_close_other_point:
                    return  # start again

# only reach if we haven't found a close point
try:
    blocks[i, j, k].append(new_point)
except KeyError:
    # create new block
    blocks[i, j, k] = [new_point]
```

There's a trade-off between how many blocks you want to store and how many neighbours you need to check. Some additional points:

- You don't want to store every block, instead just handle when the block doesn't exist yet (`KeyError`) as being empty. In the worst case you will need as many blocks as points if you do it lazily like this.
- You could use `itertools.product` to avoid the nested for loop.
- If you play with the size of blocks you could also introduce extra skipping conditions, e.g. if you know you likely can't fit more than `n` points in a block, then you just need to check `len(block[i, j, k]) > n`.
- A pure python implementation might not be fastest, you could look into speed things up using http://numba.pydata.org/, which is very easy and fast for these sorts of numeric problem whilst still reading like python.

---

EDIT: an implementation.

```
import itertools
import numpy as np
from math import ceil
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D


def compute_min_distances(ps):
    """Compute the minimum distances between all points ``ps``,
    with shape (num_points, num_dims).
    """
    ndim = ps.shape[-1]
    p1, p2 = ps.reshape(-1, 1, ndim), ps.reshape(1, -1, ndim)
    dd = np.sum((p1 - p2)**2, -1)**0.5
    # want to ignore distance to self
    np.fill_diagonal(dd, np.inf)
    return np.min(dd, axis=0)


def get_block_indices(p, B):
    """Given B blocks, get the indices of ``p``.
    """
    return [int(c * B) for c in p]


def init_blocks(ps, B):
    """Set up the initial block mapping.
    """
    blocks = {}
    for p in ps:
        i, j, k = get_block_indices(p, B)
        try:
            blocks[i, j, k].append(p)
        except KeyError:
            blocks[i, j, k] = [p]
    return blocks


def distance(p1, p2):
    """Distance bewtween two points.
    """
    return sum((a - b)**2 for a, b in zip(p1, p2))**0.5


def gen_close_points(p0s, D=0.03, N=1000):
    """Takes ``p0s`` and generates ``N`` new points with each of 
    which has a closest neighbour +- 10% of ``D``.
    """
    # number of blocks required so that only neigbours matter
    B = ceil(1 / D)

    # mapping of blocks to points
    blocks = init_blocks(p0s, B)

    n = 0
    while n < N:
        new_p = np.random.rand(3)
        i, j, k = get_block_indices(new_p, B)

        neighbour_inds = [(b - 1, b, b + 1) for b in (i, j, k)]

        def gen_neighbours():
            for ai, aj, ak in itertools.product(*neighbour_inds):
                try:
                    # try yielding each point
                    yield from blocks[ai, aj, ak]
                except KeyError:
                    # skip if empty
                    continue

        ds = (distance(new_p, p) for p in gen_neighbours())
        min_d = min(ds, default=0)

        if 0.9 * D < min_d < 1.1 * D:
            try:
                blocks[i, j, k].append(new_p)
            except KeyError:
                blocks[i, j, k] = [new_p]
            n += 1

    # combine into array of all points
    return np.concatenate(tuple(itertools.chain(blocks.values())))
```

Let's give it a whirl with some initial points:

```
p0s = np.random.rand(100, 3)
d0s = compute_min_distances(p0s)
plt.hist(d);
```

[image]

Now let's generate 10000 more points, each with closest distance specified:

```
ps = gen_close_points(p0s, 0.03, 10000)
```

And check the distances:

```
plt.hist(compute_min_distances(ps));
```

[image]

Looks good! Finally lets plot the old points and new points together:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter3D(ps[:, 0], ps[:, 1], ps[:, 2], alpha=0.1)
ax.scatter3D(p0s[:, 0], p0s[:, 1], p0s[:, 2])
```

[image]

This currently assumes that the data is 3-dimensional with range (0, 1) but should be a decent starting point for generalizing it.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, I added the code.. hope it's okay with the length, I don't know if looking at the "interesting part" is self sufficient. Blocks are probably a good idea, however I'll have to take some time to think about how to implement them in my code.

Comment: I'm afraid your posted code could do with being a lot more minimal i.e. *just* a function that takes the input and calculates the output for the problem you are asking about. Am I right that these are the core steps: 1) take a set of points 2) generate N more random points with the condition that each's closest neighbour is ``D`` +- 10%? Try reducing your code to just that bit.

Comment: amazing results ! I'll have to try to understand your code. For now as you're right about my code, I changed for a light version which works on its own, as you can see if you try, the time it takes goes up really fast. But let's try your version :)

Comment: Yes your example is much better now! I would just note a couple of things about using numpy - 1) you want to avoid looping over arrays, numpy's advantage comes when the loops are implicit and done under the hood in C (i.e. you act on the whole array at once) - see `compute_min_distances` above. 2) You want to avoid changing the size of the arrays a lot - e.g. `np.stack` or `np.delete` as this often involves copying the whole array. These things are obviously fine and useful sometimes but they shouldn't form the core of numpy code.

Comment: Just as an example, after you generate `a, b` could just compute `DCN` as `DCN = np.min(np.sqrt((A - a)**2 + (B - b)**2))`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tips ! I really can see the difference now, the code takes 10 sec for 100 000 points now instead of 20 minutes at least. Also I had to upgrade python from 2.7 to 3.5 it's great now. Thanks for your time, I will update the topic if I have some other mysterious points :). I'll put the updated code in the first post. NB : just one problem, I still have to add the item in the array if it fits the constraints. I tried it here and it's still very fast. Maybe if you have an other suggestion..

Comment: Previously you were adding then removing a point every iteration, so I think it's much more acceptable now. And no worries! Welcome to stackexchange, you might consider marking this answer (or another if it comes along) as [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)